# why php unlink cannot delete .git files?

Tags: php

error like this:

```
unlink(C:\www\program_bulter\runtime\source\program\62fc5bba68bfd\20220818110106\source\smart_agriculture\.git\objects\pack\pack-cecd0ead167cdb95559db20cf5a039f   
  055aa1406.idx): Permission denied
```

code like this:

```
        $working_directory = App::getRuntimePath() . 'source/program/';

        $local_adapter = new Local($working_directory);

        $file_system = new Filesystem($local_adapter);

        $list_content = $file_system->listContents('/');

        foreach ($list_content as $content_item) {

            $output->writeln('删除目录：' . $content_item['path']);

            if ($content_item['type'] == 'dir') {
                $file_system->deleteDir($content_item['path']);
            } else {
                $file_system->delete($content_item['path']);
            }
        }
        $output->info('清空目录完成：' . $working_directory);
```

why php unlink cannot delete files in `.git`?

how to delete those.

==========================update=====================

The `git` dir,is run with `exec`,like:

```
$run_command->run(['git', 'clone', $program->git_url, 'sourcecode']);
```

then I want to delete the dir.but it shows `Permission denied`.

How's that possible,I run this in Windows 10.

==========================update===================

I have solved this problem by other means.
Finally, there is no way to delete it directly `.git`. Although the creator or executor of these files is the same user, this user does not have permission. The 'system' permission that should be used for deleting in the resource manager can be deleted.
I have no way to execute PHP with administrator privileges in windows, and there is really no reliable way.
Finally, I use CMD's' Rd 'command to delete relevant files, as follows:

```
$run_command->run(['git', 'clone', $program->git_url, 'sourcecode', '--depth=1']);

if (strpos(strtolower(PHP_OS), 'win') === 0) {
    $run_command->run(['rd', '/s', '/q', win_path($working_directory . '/sourcecode/.git/')], null, 'cmd');
} else {
    $run_command->run(['rm -rf ./sourcecode/.git']);
}
```

Comment: It looks like a permission issue, where the process is running as something not priviledged enough to delete that particular file. I am unfamiliar with the way Windows does that.

Comment: Is it possible you have a Git tool (shell extension, your IDE...) that's keeping the file locked?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not related to the file extension. The problem here seems to be that php doesn’t have permission to delete this file. There are several ways you could solve this. In php.ini you will find the php username. Unless that username has permission to delete the file you won’t be able to